# How can I simply convert UTC offset int value in seconds to ISO format

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I need to get timezone UTC offset in the standard ISO format (for example, for "Europe/Berlin" I want «UTC+01:00» during standard time and «UTC+02:00» during DST.
QTimeZone::OffsetName does not work properly in my OS:

```
QTimeZone timeZone(«Europe/Berlin»);
String utcOffset = timeZone.displayName(QDateTime::currentDateTime(), QTimeZone::OffsetName);
QDebug(utcOffset);
```

Output in Ubuntu will be right, but in my OS it get me abbreviation name: CET

So I decide to convert QTimeZone::offsetFromUtc to ISO format.

```
 QTimeZone timeZone(«Europe/Berlin»);
 int utcOffset = timeZone.offsetFromUtc(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
```

Does Qt have tools to get the string I need in one step?

Comment: Well, looks like `offsetFromUtc` gives you the number of seconds, so there you go? Are you simply asking how to take the number of seconds, and format it as `UTC+/-hh:mm`? Did you try dividing the number of seconds by 60, and taking the remainder of the division by 60, and simply formatting the results? Do you understand what `UTC+/-hh:mm` actually means? What, specifically, is unclear to you about it?

Comment: I understand, problem is that manually dividing number of second by 60 looks odd to me, especially considering the fact that everyting else is made using builtin QDateTime methods. Question is "Does Qt have tools to get the string I need in one step?"

Answer (score 0):

Which weird OS and which Qt version exactly do you use? Qt actually hard codes displayName with QTimeZone::OffsetName into

```
QString QTimeZonePrivate::isoOffsetFormat(int offsetFromUtc)
{
    const int mins = offsetFromUtc / 60;
    return QString::fromUtf8("UTC%1%2:%3").arg(mins >= 0 ? QLatin1Char('+') : QLatin1Char('-'))
                                          .arg(qAbs(mins) / 60, 2, 10, QLatin1Char('0'))
                                          .arg(qAbs(mins) % 60, 2, 10, QLatin1Char('0'));
}
```

so it is extremely hard to believe, that you get CET as a result.